# Is it possible to access AWS Cognito API with access token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a simple application consisting of two modules - OAuth2 client (Spring Cloud Gateway) and OAuth2 resource. I use AWS Cognito as an identity provider. Some users with specific roles should be able to create/update/delete other Cognito users.

I'm going to use `aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp` library for integration with AWS Cognito API, but I need to make this calls as a current logged-in user, to be able to check user's groups and IAM roles. Because users from different groups should have different privileges.

I found `AWSSessionCredentialsProvider` that seems suitable for this task, but there is no implementation.

I implemented this provider to get access token from the `SecurityContext`. When I call the API I get an error:

> The security token included in the request is invalid

Is it possible to use user's access token as a credentials for `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have app to login with given user with his credentials -

```
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoIdentityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(getSDKCredentials()))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(getAwsRegion()))
                .build();

    Map<String,String> params =new HashMap<>();
        params.put("USERNAME", userName);
        params.put("PASSWORD", passCode);

    AdminInitiateAuthRequest initialRequest=new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
            .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
            .withAuthParameters(params)
            .withClientId(getClientId())
            .withUserPoolId(getUserPoolId());

    AdminInitiateAuthResult response = cognitoIdentityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(initialRequest);
```

this will return your response where you have session. check if it helps-

Answer (score 0):

```
AdminInitiateAuthResult authResult = client.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
AuthenticationResultType resultType = authResult.getAuthenticationResult();
vars.put("AccessToken",resultType.getAccessToken());
vars.put("RefreshToken",resultType.getRefreshToken());
vars.put("IdToken",resultType.getIdToken());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).